# Why is 'of' used in the following sentence istead of 'to'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, verbs, grammaticality-in-context

It ill behooves you to speak so rudely **of** your parents.

How does using 'of' changes it's natural meaning?

Could you give me **more examples** of such type of sentences?

Answer (score 1):

If you speak **to** your parents, you address them directly.

If you speak **of** them, you say something about them, possibly in their absence.

Comment: Seems sensible  thanks